# Sandisk usb encrypt stick not working

Tags: windows-10, usb, encryption

So i have recently found my old usb stick and i want to use encryptstick but i displays a non-helpful error like this (see below) [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnaAN.png)  can anyone help me troubleshoot this error?

I only used one pc to make the vault and that is apparently the place i did not create the vault according to the sandisk :( Thanks,Jac

[image]

Answer (score 0):

unninstalled it and re-installed it. works. stupidity hitted me in my face